# while Installing the VB.Net exe file getting this error "microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.vs version 10.0.0.0 be installed in the GAC"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working on VB.Net project. I have published the new version of file (.EXE), When I run that EXE I am getting the below error. this is really new for me. I don't know how to fix that.

**Error:**

**"Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly
microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.vs version 10.0.0.0 be installed in the GAC first.
Please contact your system admin"**

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're just missing that dependency. You could either install it separately or include in in an install package for your project.

[This download link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=145727&clcid=0x804)  that I found on [this forum listing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67665b95-0339-421f-a0a5-c20c60c57e15/microsoft-visual-basic-power-packs-100?forum=vbpowerpacks) will get you the download.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply and I will try this later.

Meanwhile i fixed the issue by removing the microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks in project properties -> reference tab. 

it works well but i dont know this is the permanenet fix.

Comment: Depends on whether anything in that library is being used in your project. Have a look at the [project page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx) to see. It might have just been an old reference left in.